# Looping (or applying?) over all combinations of two factor levels

Tags: r, combinatorics, tidyverse

The first 9 rows of my long data frame look like this:

```
  ptid<-c(rep(3, 3), rep(4, 3), rep(5, 3))
  reviewer<-c("d", "b", "f", "a", "e", "c", "a", "f", "b")
  outcome<-c(rep("Yes", 2), rep("No", 4), rep("Yes", 3))
  dta <- data.frame(ptid, reviewer, outcome, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Each value of `ptid` is repeated exactly 3 times within dta.
There are 6 values of the `reviewer` variable `a:f`, and the outcome variable is binary without any missing data.

I made an empty matrix that looks like this:

```
mat<-matrix(, nrow=6, ncol=6, dimnames = list(letters[1:6], letters[1:6]))
```

I'd like to fill the bottom half of the matrix with the percentage of times that each combination of reviewers agreed with each other.  I can do this for position `[a,b]` in the matrix using the following code:

```
combo<-dta[which(dta$reviewer=="a" | dta$reviewer=="b"), c("ptid", "reviewer", "outcome")]
wide<-combo %>% spread(reviewer, outcome)
wide<-na.omit(wide)
ab_agree<-table(wide$a==wide$b)[2]
ab<-paste(signif((ab_agree/dim(wide)[1])*100, 3), "%", sep="")
mat["a", "b"]<-ab
```

I would greatly appreciate help writing a function that fills each column of the matrix in the most efficient way possible.  I initially started writing a `for` loop but I have a feeling there's a better way with `apply`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use `apply` or a `for`-loop but functions from `dplyr` and `tidyr` (as you are using already those packages).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
```

First I get all combinations of all reviewer pairs:

```
reviewer_combos <- tibble(reviewer1 = letters[1:6], reviewer2 = letters[1:6]) %>% 
  complete(reviewer1, reviewer2) %>% 
  filter(reviewer1 != reviewer2)

reviewer_combos
# A tibble: 30 x 2
#    reviewer1 reviewer2
#    <chr>     <chr>    
#  1 a         b        
#  2 a         c        
#  3 a         d        
#  4 a         e        
#  5 a         f        
#  6 b         a        
#  7 b         c        
#  8 b         d        
#  9 b         e        
# 10 b         f        
# ... with 20 more rows
```

Then join the answers of reviwer1 and reviwer2 to the data with two `left_join`s and determine whether they agree:

```
reviewer_combos <- reviewer_combos %>% 
  left_join(dta, by = c("reviewer1" = "reviewer")) %>% 
  left_join(dta, by = c("reviewer2" = "reviewer"), suffix = c("", "2")) %>% 
  mutate(agree = as.integer(outcome == outcome2))

reviewer_combos
# A tibble: 66 x 7
#    reviewer1 reviewer2  ptid outcome ptid2 outcome2 agree
#    <chr>     <chr>     <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <chr>    <int>
#  1 a         b          4.00 No       3.00 Yes          0
#  2 a         b          4.00 No       5.00 Yes          0
#  3 a         b          5.00 Yes      3.00 Yes          1
#  4 a         b          5.00 Yes      5.00 Yes          1
#  5 a         c          4.00 No       4.00 No           1
#  6 a         c          5.00 Yes      4.00 No           0
#  7 a         d          4.00 No       3.00 Yes          0
#  8 a         d          5.00 Yes      3.00 Yes          1
#  9 a         e          4.00 No       4.00 No           1
# 10 a         e          5.00 Yes      4.00 No           0
# ... with 56 more rows
```

Finally determine the percentage of agreement in each reviwer group with `group_by` and `summarize` and display them in the format you want to have with `spread`:

```
reviewer_percentage <- reviewer_combos %>% 
  group_by(reviewer1, reviewer2) %>% 
  summarize(percentage_agree = sum(agree)/n()) %>% 
  spread(reviewer2, percentage_agree) 

reviewer_percentage
# A tibble: 6 x 7
# Groups:   reviewer1 [6]
# reviewer1      a      b      c      d      e      f
# * <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 a         NA      0.500  0.500  0.500  0.500  0.500
# 2 b          0.500 NA      0      1.00   0      0.500
# 3 c          0.500  0     NA      0      1.00   0.500
# 4 d          0.500  1.00   0     NA      0      0.500
# 5 e          0.500  0      1.00   0     NA      0.500
# 6 f          0.500  0.500  0.500  0.500  0.500 NA
```

If you need to have it as a `matrix` and with the upper triangular part being `NA` you can do it like this:

```
reviewer_percentage_mat <- reviewer_percentage %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-reviewer1) %>% 
  as.matrix()

rownames(reviewer_percentage_mat) <- reviewer_percentage$reviewer1
reviewer_percentage_mat[upper.tri(reviewer_percentage_mat)] <-  NA

reviewer_percentage_mat
#    a   b   c   d   e  f
# a  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA NA
# b 0.5  NA  NA  NA  NA NA
# c 0.5 0.0  NA  NA  NA NA
# d 0.5 1.0 0.0  NA  NA NA
# e 0.5 0.0 1.0 0.0  NA NA
# f 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 NA
```

**Data**

```
dta <- structure(list(ptid = c(3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5), 
                      reviewer = c("d", "b", "f", "a", "e", "c", "a", "f", "b"), 
                      outcome = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes")), 
                 .Names = c("ptid", "reviewer", "outcome"), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -9L), 
                 class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi Kath, You got me 95% of the way there.  After the two left joins and mutate command I needed to add `reviewer_combos<-reviewer_combos[which(reviewer_combos$ptid==reviewer_combos$ptid2), ]` and then it worked perfectly.  Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: It wasn't clear from your question, that they have to aggree on the `ptid` as well. You can also simply add `%>% filter(ptid == ptid2)` after the `mutate` call.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear in my question.  I agree the filter command is more aesthetically pleasing.